# Out of range string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, object

Hey guys im getting an out of range error for a string.at(x) and I have no idea why. Any help, basically i am trying to make sure the first character is no < 'A' or > 'z' in my object string. Also I think my string comparison may not be working properly, but that may have more to do with unfinished code if i find unique word that has duplicates.

```
struct wordCount{
string word;
int count;
}storeword[100];

void countWordFreq(wordCount compares[]){
int a=0;
unsigned i=0;
for(a;a<101;a++){
    cout<<"Length"<<compares[a].word.length();
    if(compares[a].word.at(i)<='z'||compares[a].word.at(i)>='A'){       
    compares[a].count++;
    }
    for(int b=1;b<101;b++){
        cout<<"Length"<<compares[b].word.length();
        if(compares[b].word.at(i)<='z'||compares[b].word.at(i)>='A'){           
        if(compares[a].word.compare(compares[b].word)==0){
            cout<<"true" << endl;
            compares[a].count++;
        }
    }
        b++;
    }
    a++;

}
for(int q;/*compare[q].word.at(0)<='z'||compare[q].word.at(0)>='A'*/q<10;q++){
    cout<<"Word: " << compares[q].word << " Count: " << compares[q].count << endl;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm guessing the size of the array `compares` is `100`. If so, the array index counters `a` and `b` need to be less that `100`, not less than `101`. When the value of `a` or `b` is `100`, you will get undefined behavior due to accessing out of range memory.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. At the risk of sounding (being? -- if so, sorry) impolite, I think I'd do this job quite a bit differently.

The C++ standard library provides quite a few tools to do this job much more easily, with a lot less chance of hard-to-find bugs and such. I'd put them to use.

Just for what it's worth: I wasn't sure I quite understood the comparison you described for the first character of each word. For the moment I'm assuming you want to only count things that start with letters. It's easy enough to change that if needed, though.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>

void countWordFreq(std::string const &input) {
    std::map<std::string, size_t> counts;

    std::istringstream buffer(input);

    std::string word;

    // read the words, count frequencies of those that start with letters
    while (buffer >> word)
        if (isalpha(word[0]))
            ++counts[word];

    // write out each word we found and how often it occurred:
    for (auto const &count : counts)
        std::cout << std::setw(20) << count.first << ": " << count.second << "\n";
}
```

As it stands, this will print out the unique words in alphabetical order. If you don't need that ordering, you can (usually) increase speed somewhat by using an `std::unordered_map` instead of a `std::map`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry i am still new to programming and not very familiar with all the libraries and what they offer, as well as using them correctly. I can't run it since map is not declared.

Comment: @user3051442: You need to include `<map>` to get the declaration. You'll need some other headers as well. I'll edit them in.